# Set alignment of a toolstriptextbox

Tags: winforms, toolstrip

I have a form with a Toolstrip along the top. 
On this toolbar I have a toolstrip button which I've set the alignment to "Right" and it now appears on the far right of the toolstrip.

I now want to add a toolStripTextBox but when I right-click on it I don't get the option to align it. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alignment property is available in the property grid, it just isn't available on the popup menu.

If you don't see the Properties window, type CTRL+W, P.

Comment: Thanks! I did check on the properties grid but managed to miss it somehow.